# Returning str and int From a Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am defining a function that asks a user to input their name and then a number that corresponds to the action they want to take and store as `decision`.  I want the function to return the player name and `decision` for use in engaging other parts of the program.

When I first executed this program it completed `startup()` fine but did not engage the `if` statement.  I then put in `print("Made to here, %s, %i" %(player_name, decision))` to see what the function was returning.  It throws a type error at this line stating that `decision` is being returned as a type and not an integer.

```
def startup():
    player_name = str(input("Hail and well met. What is your name?  "))
    decision = int(input(player_name+", enter 0 to play and 1 for result statistics."))
    return (player_name, decision)

startup()
print("Made to here, %s, %i" %(player_name, decision))

if decision == 0:
    print("Game time!")
elif decision == 1:
    print("Let's see how you've done.")
```

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question.  Notice that you're returning `player_name` and `decision`, but not capturing those return values anywhere.  That means that those values are lost, and the rest of your code does not know about them.

Comment: Check `global` dude.... working code here https://repl.it/repls/PutridMicroGeeklog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are local to your function. Don't use `global` here, just unpack:

```
player_name, decision = startup()
```

Comment: Simple solution, I see now. So if I don't direct that returned variables are being stored somewhere Python is just going to return their states?

Comment: You should see NameError in a new session.